# NoReverseMatch and urls.py

Tags: python, django

I am getting a `TemplateSyntaxError` whenever I try to run a search using [gitpaste](https://github.com/justinvh/gitpaste/):

```
<a href='{% url owner_pastes owner=result.object.owner.pk %}'>
      {{ result.object.owner }}
</a>
```

The urls.py is laid out as:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('saic.paste.views',
    url(r'^live/$', 'live_paste', name='live_paste'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/paste/%(pk)s/'}),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', redirect_to, {'url': '/paste/%(pk)s/%(private_key)s/'}),
    url(r'^owner/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/owner/all/'}),
    url(r'^owner/anonymous/', 'user_pastes', name='anon_pastes'),
    url(r'^owner/(?P<owner>.+)/', 'user_pastes', name='user_pastes'),
    url(r'^paste/(?P<pk>\d+)/adopt/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', 'paste_adopt', name='paste_adopt'),
    url(r'^paste/(?P<pk>\d+)/embed/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', 'paste_embed', name='paste_embed'),
    url(r'^paste/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', 'paste_edit', name='paste_edit'),
    url(r'^paste/(?P<pk>\d+)/fork/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', 'paste_fork', name='paste_fork'),
    url(r'^paste/(?P<pk>\d+)/favorite/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', 'paste_favorite', name='paste_favorite'),
    url(r'^paste/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', 'paste_delete', name='paste_delete'),
    url(r'^paste/(?P<pk>\d+)/raw/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', 'paste_raw', name='paste_raw'),
    url(r'^commit/(?P<pk>.+)/adopt/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', 'commit_adopt', name='commit_adopt'),
    url(r'^commit/(?P<pk>.+)/download/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', 'commit_download', name='commit_download'),
    url(r'^paste/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<private_key>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$', 'paste_view', name='paste_view'),
    url(r'^users/$', 'users', name='users'),
    url(r'^favorites/$', 'favorites', name='favorites'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'login', name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'logout', name='logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'register', name='register'),
    url(r'^accounts/preference/$', 'preference', name='preference'),
    url(r'^accounts/timezone/$', 'set_timezone', name='set_timezone'),
    url(r'^$', 'paste', name='paste'),
)
```

From reading the Django documentation, it seems that I need a url pattern for `owner`. This is the rest of the error I am getting:

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'owner_pastes' with
>   arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'owner': 5}' not found.

It looks like the URL is there. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the URL is not `owner_pastes` but `user_pastes` according to the following line:

```
 url(r'^owner/(?P<owner>.+)/', 'user_pastes', name='user_pastes'),
```

Try this:

```
<a href='{% url user_pastes owner=result.object.owner.pk %}'>{{ result.object.owner }}</a>
```

Side-note: be careful, with Django >= 1.5, you need to surround the first parameter by quotes (otherwise it is treated as a variable):

```
<a href='{% url "user_pastes" owner=result.object.owner.pk %}'>{{ result.object.owner }}</a>
```

Comment: No problem. For this kind of error, first look if you don't have made a typo in the URL name (here `owner_` instead of `user_`) or in the number of parameters. It will kill ~90% of your `{% url %}` problems ;)

Comment: Actually there are some changes b/w django 1.4 & 1.5. In 1.4 you can do like `{% url handler-name argname0='arg0' argname1='arg1' %}` but syntax changes in 1.5 to `{% url 'handler-name' ...%}`.. probably your syntax error is here

Comment: @Surya Indeed, little sidenote added to emphasize this